# Can a irreversible chain has a transition matrix of the time-reversal

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

A chain is time-reversible if and only if it satisfies the detailed balance condition.
If it doesn't satisfy the condition, can I still compute the transition matrix of the time-reversal by $P_{ij}= \pi_jP_{ji}/\pi_i$

Answer (score 0):

If $\pi$ is the stationary distribution for the chain, then (assuming $X_0$ has $\pi$ for its distribution) the time-reversed chain is Markovian wuth transition matrix as you indicate: $P^*_{ij}=\pi_jP_{ji}/\pi_i$. The time reversal I have in mind is this: Fix a time $N>0$ and consider
$$
X^*_n:=X_{N-n},\qquad n=0,1,2,\ldots,N.
$$